# Java EE, Servlets , JSP - Filter Issues

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, filter

My code:

sessionFilter.java

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

    if (session == null) {
        res.sendRedirect("errorPage.jsp");
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.sessionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/loginSuccess.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

loginSuccess.jsp

```
Logged successfull, Hello
            <p style="color: blue"><%=request.getSession().getAttribute("User")%></p>

            <form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Logout">
            </form>
```

The first time when i run loginSuccess.jsp it correctly redirect me to errorPage.jsp but when i do it more times it show me loginSuccess.jsp page with session attribute null. Where I made mistake? I create session with `session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);`

Comment: Where do you put the user attribute on the session ?

Comment: What code is in errorPage.jsp? Maybe that is where the session is being created.

Answer (score 0):

loginServlet.java

```
 try {
                    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from User u where u.email = :email", User.class).setParameter("email", email);;
                    User userEmail = (User) q.getSingleResult();
                    if (email.equals(userEmail.getEmail()) && password.equals(userEmail.getPassword())) {
                        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
                        session.setAttribute("User", email);
                        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginSuccess.jsp");
                        rd.include(request, response); 
    } else .....
```

errorPage.jsp

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1><a href="index.jsp">LIBRARY</a></h1>
        <div class="topbar">
            <a href="register.jsp">Register</a> <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
            <div class="menu">MENU</div>
            <div class="main">ERROR</div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <br>

    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Yes, errorPage.jsp   creates a session So subsequent requests would pass your filter. You could add session="false" to it's page directive. But really your Filter should be checking for the "user" session attribute  as @jMounir asked you about.

Comment: Why are you using  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1); ?  An interval value of zero or less indicates that the session should never timeout.

Comment: I found in google, when i'm setting MaxInactiveInterval(-1) session will be invalidate on browser close,  now i think that's wrong. BTW Can you explain me how session is created in this page?

Comment: A JSP automatically creates a session unless you direct it not to.    If you are using Tomcat, then look in it's work folder for the translated file. The code is there.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem by this way:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
         Object user = session.getAttribute("User");
        if (user == null) {
            res.sendRedirect("errorPage.jsp");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
```